# speed up join on string field

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-workbench, query-optimization

I have a table with data like the tableA example below.  the date column is formatted as a string.
the close column is an integer, ticker is formatted as string.
I'm trying to run the query below on a mysql database and it is taking a very long time.
is there anything I can do to speed this up, like changing the format of the date column, or adding
indices or primary keys?  The combination of ticker and date should be a unique value, and the date field is a timestamp, it's just currently formatted as string.

code:

```
select avg((a.close-b.close)/b.close) as avg_annual_returns,
a.ticker
from tableA a 
join tableA b
on cast(a.date as date)=date_add(cast(b.date as date),interval 365 DAY)
and a.ticker=b.ticker
where b.close is not null
group by a.ticker
```

tableA

```
+--------+-----+------+
|date    |close|ticker|
+--------+-----+------+
|2/1/2019|5    |abc   |
+--------+-----+------+
|2/3/2019|7    |efd   |
+--------+-----+------+
|2/4/2019|3    |hij   |
+--------+-----+------+
```

update answer:

```
select ticker,date, ( -1 +
        a.close / max(a.close) over (partition by ticker 
                                     order by date
                                     range between interval 365 day preceding and interval 365 day preceding
                                    ) 
       ) as annual_returns              
from tableA a
) b where annual_returns is not null
group by ticker
```

Comment: What are your table and index definitions?

Comment: Expression in joining condition? None index may help (except the index by generated column which uses the expression from joining condition - literally).

Comment: If you have MySQL version 8+ or MariaDB 10.2+ the windowing functions will work. Otherwise not.

Comment: @O.Jones thank you for the tip.  I'm on mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64), running on ubuntu server.  do I need to upgrade?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to upgrade, but @gordonLInoff's code won't work on v 5.7.33.  Note that they jumped from v5.7 to v8.x, so you didn't miss 6 or 7.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the difference from a year ago, then use window functions.  Before that, though, fix the data model!  Do not store dates as strings.  So:

```
alter table talbeA modify column date date;
```

Then to get the close from a year ago:

```
select( -1 +
        a.close / max(a.close) over (partition by ticker 
                                     order by date
                                     range between interval 365 day preceding and interval 365 day preceding
                                    )
       )               
from tablea a;
```

You don't have to worry about `NULL` values because `AVG()` ignores them.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cfb10558d80e6a2185b2439d1f6b8fd6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  The logic on your suggestion is a little complicated, can you please explain it a little more?  also I don't understand how the 'b' alias works?  I tried running your code but it seems to have a syntax error.

Comment: @user3476463 . . . That was a typo.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: thank you again for the help.  I'm still getting an error with the new version with the alias fixed.  are you sure this works in mysql?

Comment: @user3476463 . . . I fixed the errors and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you your suggestion works great.  I added an update with the final answer to my original post.  I had to upgrade mysql to 8, and play with your code a litter but runs plenty fast!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
on cast(a.date as date)=date_add(cast(b.date as date),interval 365 DAY)
```

Both sides of that are not "sargeable", so it can't use any index.

Assuming `date` is datatype `DATE`, then this works:

```
ON a.date = b.date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

Also, have

```
INDEX(ticker, date)   -- in this order.
```

Note:  `1 YEAR` will hiccup around Feb 28; `365 DAY` will hiccup for 366 days ever 4 years.

Also, change

```
where b.close is not null
```

to

```
WHERE b.ticker IS NOT NULL
```

(Functionally they are the same, but I picked a column in the index, just in case it matters.)  Well, OK, are there any rows where `close` is NULL?

Oh, another issue.  Because of weekends, only 3 or 4 days of each week can find a matching day in the previous year.